# Click button w/ image in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, userscripts

The issue I'm having is that this RPG that I play on has an image inside of the button, literally. And I have no idea how I can simulate a click in Javascript with this.

This is the HTML of the button.

```
<button class="forward inputsubmitflex" onclick="return do_attack(this, event.clientX, event.clientY, event);"><img src="/images/icons/RubyHoundour.png">Fight</button>
```

I've tried the following snippets of code to try to click this button, but they haven't worked.

```
$( ".forward inputsubmitflex" ).click(function()
```

That didn't work though.. so I have no idea what to do.. D:
Here is how the button looks, if it helps at all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xhOP.png

^That's a picture of the button. :c

Any help at all? I'm willing to do this in jQuery, as I posted my jQuery snippet above, but I'd prefer Javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, the space in the selector is what is messing it up. You would need to do:

```
$(".forward.inputsubmitflex").click(function()
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/LNa9R/

If you are just trying to trigger the click event, you should use this:

```
$(".forward.inputsubmitflex").trigger("click");
```

Although, clicking on the button will automatically fire the onclick event. If you are trying to trigger the button by clicking elsewhere this Fiddle should help: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/LNa9R/3/

Comment: Hmm..I tried to execute that snip in the console, and it returns with

SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Not sure why? Maybe our snippets are incorrect for the button?

Comment: What is the complete snippet you are using? It sounds like there is something missing as it is coming across the } to soon.

Comment: I don't have a complete snippet, to be honest, since I'm so befuddled and confused at how to even process a code to get the button clicked.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is trigger the click event, you should actually use: $(".forward.inputsubmitflex").trigger("click");